# Error "name "true" not defined when sending POST request

Tags: python, rest, post, python-requests

I am trying to send a POST request that requires the literal `true` to be sent as part of the JSON payload. I know I can change it to `True` which Python likes but it fails with an API (SCIM) that I am testing.

How do I send the word `true` and have Python submit it as-is? This does work when I send via Postman. Using an example with httpbin below with the same error.

```
import requests

headers = {
            "Accept": "Application/json",
            "Content-Type": "Application/json"
        }       


payload = {
    "emails": [{
        "primary": true,
        "value": "jack@justjack.com",
        "type": "work"
    }]
 }

print (type (payload))  

print (payload)

resp = requests.post ('http://httpbin.com/post',headers=headers,data=payload)
print(resp.content)
```

Error Message I get is

```
   "primary": true,
NameError: name 'true' is not defined"
```

Comment: I guess it should be `True` not `true`

Comment: It should've been `True` instead

Comment: It should be `True`

Comment: If you want the literal "true" then use `"true"`.

Comment: Okay, now that I've read the question (which says: "I know I can change it to "True" which Python likes but it fails with an API (SCIM) that I am testing"), if you want to send literally `true`, just send the string `"true"` maybe?

Comment: No, "True" breaks the API I am testing. It needs to be true. It also doesn't like it in quotes so it has to as-sent in example above. For example, when testing with HTTP BIN it returns what i am sending as-is:  "json": {
    "emails": [
      {
        "primary": true, 
        "type": "work", 
        "value": "jack@justjack.com"
      }
    ]
  },

Comment: [Please don't add "solved" to your title or question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/116105/248627). Instead, [mark an answer correct by clicking on the checkmark](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/248627). You can also [add your own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) and accept it if none of the ones you received solved your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Python's regular `True` and convert your `dict` to a JSON string when you create your payload:

```py
import json

payload = {
    "emails": [{
        "primary": True,
        "value": "jack@justjack.com",
        "type": "work"
    }]
 }

resp = requests.post('http://httpbin.com/post', headers=headers, data=json.dumps(payload))
#                                                                     ^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: I needed the True to be true but you gave me a great idea Chris. I got it working. Posting updated code above.

Comment: @jeyyu2003, the `True` _will be_ `true` here. JSON comes from JavaScript where the Boolean true literal is `true`. Python's Boolean true literal is `True`. The `json` module knows this and generates the appropriate output when it converts in either direction.

Comment: @jeyyu2003, building a Python dict and converting to JSON automatically with something baked into the standard library is _much_ more robust than manually building a JSON string as you have done. I strongly advise you to actually try the code in my answer. It does what you want.

Comment: I stand corrected. your code does work. I was hung over the fact that I needed to change my payload true to True but make  sense after your comment about JSON changing it to lowercase. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

in python we are using `True` or `False` instead of true / false
you can read further here in [PEP-285](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0285/)